# Delete row based on column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have Google Sheets where I need to delete all the rows IF the Column contains the number 0. Any quick way to do this? I have over 20000 rows to go through and I don't want to do this manually.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research to see if there are good ways of doing it?

Comment: You could export to a desktop spreadsheet program and do it there, and then import it back again.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and old style method is sort on that column so that all the rows having that column value '0' are together. Then select all those rows using Ctrl + Page Down and then press delete. NO need to explore any fancy options for such simple things.

Another quicker option is to use `filter`. Select the column and then click `Filter` under the Data menu. Then from the drop down, select '0' for the filter by values. This will hide all the rows that don't contain 0 in that column. Then simply select all those rows and delete them.